# order forced to close for the next order to open pinescript

Tags: pine-script

ok so I have this code

```
if (longCond and not (strategy.position_size > 0))
    strategy.entry("long", strategy.long)
    strategy.exit("close", "long", limit = (close[1] * 1.05) , stop = (close[1] * 0.95))
```

and even with my attempt to prevent orders opening while another order is open what happens is
if longCond is true and the position is not closed, it will force-close the position to be able to open another long position after the candle close.
how do I prevent this

Comment: What's the short conditions? add the full code. This one works as expected. Did you tried `if (longCond and strategy.position_size == 0)`?

Comment: There are no short conditions yet as the long is not functioning properly.
lets say the entry price is 60000.0... 60300.0 is the expected outcome but I have instances in my history where the trade is closed much higher.
and vice versa, I have instances where the stoploss is triggered far too soon, sometimes even instantly